# tensorflow.GraphDef was modified concurrently during serialization

Tags: python, tensorflow, multi-gpu

I use python and tensorflow,

My GPU is Tesla V100, has 4 GPUs, when I set:

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
```

or

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,1'
```

or

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,1,2'
```

the code can run without any error.

but when I use the full GPUs, and set:

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,1,2,3'

the program can't run, and throw an error msg:

"

tensorflow.GraphDef was modified concurrently during serialization.

"

the detailed error msg is :

"

[libprotobuf FATAL external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:68] CHECK failed: (byte_size_before_serialization) == (byte_size_after_serialization): tensorflow.GraphDef was modified concurrently during serialization.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  CHECK failed: (byte_size_before_serialization) == (byte_size_after_serialization): tensorflow.GraphDef was modified concurrently during serialization.
bash: line 1: 285122 Aborted                 (core dumped) env "PYCHARM_HOSTED"="1" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED"="1" "PYTHONIOENCODING"="UTF-8" "PYCHARM_MATPLOTLIB_PORT"="41215" "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "PYTHONPATH"="/home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet_onesample:/home/zhuqingjie/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend" '/home/zhuqingjie/env/py3_tf_low/bin/python' '-u' '/home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet_onesample/train.py'

"

so why?

is there a connection between GPUs used numbers and this error?

Comment: Please include your train.py script so we can see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

train.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os, time
import random
import numpy as np
from data_init import get_data
from model import UNET as G
import config

# from tensorflow.python.profiler import model_analyzer
# from tensorflow.python.profiler import option_builder

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1,2,3'

# param
epochs = config.epoch


def train():
    data_train_batch, label_train_batch, data_test_batch, label_test_batch = get_data()
    data_len = float(len(data_train_batch))
    g = G()
    open('logdir/readme', 'w').write(
        g.readme + '\n\n{}'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))))

    # launch tensorboard
    os.system('pkill tensorboard')
    os.system('rm /home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/logdir/checkpoint')
    os.system('rm /home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/logdir/event*')
    os.system('rm /home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/logdir/model_*')
    os.system('rm /home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/logdir/v/event*')
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('nohup /home/zhuqingjie/env/py3_tf_low/bin/tensorboard --logdir=/home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/logdir &')

    # 备份一份model.py
    os.system("cp /home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/model.py /home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/logdir/")

    # train
    with tf.Session(graph=g.graph) as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='logdir', graph=g.graph)
        summary_writer_v = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='logdir/v', graph=g.graph)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run([g.train_iterator.initializer, g.test_iterator.initializer],
                 feed_dict={g.train_features_placeholder: data_train_batch,
                            g.train_labels_placeholder: label_train_batch,
                            g.test_features_placeholder: data_test_batch,
                            g.test_labels_placeholder: label_test_batch})
        time_use = []
        while True:
            time_start = time.time()
            _, _, summary, loss, abs_error, gs = sess.run(
                [g.train_op_D, g.train_op_G, g.mergeall, g.loss_mse, g.abs_error, g.global_step],
                feed_dict={g.train_flag: True})
            # _ = sess.run([g.train_op_G2], feed_dict={g.train_flag: True})
            # _ = sess.run([g.train_op_G2], feed_dict={g.train_flag: True})
            # _ = sess.run([g.train_op_G2], feed_dict={g.train_flag: True})
            # _ = sess.run([g.train_op_G2], feed_dict={g.train_flag: True})
            time_end = time.time()
            time_use.append(time_end - time_start)
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary, gs)
            # val
            if gs % 10 == 0:
                _, _, summary, gs = sess.run([g.loss_mse, g.abs_error, g.mergeall, g.global_step],
                                             feed_dict={g.train_flag: False})
                summary_writer_v.add_summary(summary, gs)
                print('---------------avg_time_use:{}'.format(np.mean(np.array(time_use))))
                print('gs / data_len, gs, loss, abs_error')
                time_use = []
            # save
            if gs % 100 == 0:
                # 覆盖保存
                saver.save(sess, 'logdir/model_{}'.format(gs))

                # 每一千次保存一次model
                if gs % 1000 == 0:
                    iter_dir = '/home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/backup/iter/{}/'.format(gs)
                    os.system('mkdir {}'.format(iter_dir))
                    os.system('cp /home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/logdir/model* {}'.format(iter_dir))
                    os.system('cp /home/zhuqingjie/prj/tunet/logdir/last_random_ind.txt {}'.format(iter_dir))
            print('{:.2f} -- {} -- {:.4f} -- {:.4f}'.format(gs / data_len, gs, loss, abs_error))
            if gs / data_len > epochs: break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\n' * 5)
    print('=' * 150)
    print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time())))
    print('=' * 150)
    train()
    print('ok')
```

model.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.layers as L
from vgg16 import Vgg16 as VGG
import os
import config

# param
batch_size = config.batch_size
hw = config.hw


class UNET():
    def __init__(sf, predict_flag=False):
        print('loading UNET..')
        sf.readme = '''
        Data: {}*{}
        G: unet
        D: cnn
        Opt: adam, GAN loss + perc loss + MSE loss
        Train: 又多train了2次train_op_G2
        '''.format(config.hw, config.hw)
        sf.graph = tf.Graph()
        sf.istraining = not predict_flag
        # dataset_train, dataset_test = load_data_2()
        with sf.graph.as_default():
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                # init dataset
                sf.train_flag = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool)
                # train
                sf.train_features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, batch_size, hw, hw, 1])
                sf.train_labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, batch_size, hw, hw, 1])
                train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
                    (sf.train_features_placeholder, sf.train_labels_placeholder)).repeat()
                sf.train_iterator = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
                # test
                sf.test_features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, batch_size, hw, hw, 1])
                sf.test_labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, batch_size, hw, hw, 1])
                test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
                    (sf.test_features_placeholder, sf.test_labels_placeholder)).repeat()
                sf.test_iterator = test_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

                if not predict_flag:
                    sf.x, sf.y = sf.get_xy(sf.train_flag)
                else:
                    sf.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, hw, hw, 1])
                    sf.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, hw, hw, 1])

                # Multi GPU
                sf.opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001)
                sf.global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
                tower_grads_G = []
                tower_grads_D = []
                for gpu_i in range(len(config.gpus)):
                    with tf.device('/gpu:{}'.format(gpu_i)):
                        with tf.name_scope('tower_{}'.format(gpu_i)):
                            # split batch
                            batch_per_gpu = config.batch_per_gpu
                            x_ = sf.x[gpu_i * batch_per_gpu:(gpu_i + 1) * batch_per_gpu]
                            y_ = sf.y[gpu_i * batch_per_gpu:(gpu_i + 1) * batch_per_gpu]

                            prd = sf.gen(x_)
                            d_prd = sf.disc(prd)
                            ls_d_prd = tf.reduce_mean(d_prd)
                            loss_d_prd = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(d_prd, 1e-10, 1.0)))
                            d_y = sf.disc(y_)
                            ls_d_y = tf.reduce_mean(d_y)
                            loss_d_y = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(d_y, 1e-10, 1.0)))
                            abs_error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y_ - prd)) * 255

                            # MSE Loss
                            yr = tf.reshape(y_, [y_.shape[0], -1])
                            prdr = tf.reshape(prd, [prd.shape[0], -1])
                            loss_mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(yr, prdr)

                            # Perceptual Loss
                            vgg = VGG()
                            y_perc = vgg.forward(y_)
                            prd_perc = vgg.forward(prd)
                            yr_perc = tf.reshape(y_perc, [y_perc.shape[0], -1])
                            prdr_perc = tf.reshape(prd_perc, [prd_perc.shape[0], -1])
                            loss_perc = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(yr_perc, prdr_perc)

                            # Adversarial Loss
                            loss_G = loss_mse + loss_perc - loss_d_prd
                            loss_D = loss_d_prd - loss_d_y

                            # gard
                            var_list_G = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'generator')
                            var_list_D = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'discriminator')
                            grads_G = sf.opt.compute_gradients(loss_G, var_list=var_list_G)
                            grads_D = sf.opt.compute_gradients(loss_D, var_list=var_list_D)
                            tower_grads_G.append(grads_G)
                            tower_grads_D.append(grads_D)

                            # summary
                            if gpu_i == 0:
                                sf.loss_mse = loss_mse
                                sf.loss_perc = loss_perc
                                sf.abs_error = abs_error
                                sf.loss_G = loss_G
                                sf.loss_D = loss_D
                                sf.ls_d_prd = ls_d_prd
                                sf.ls_d_y = ls_d_y
                                sf.loss_d_prd = loss_d_prd
                                sf.loss_d_y = loss_d_y
                                sf.x_ = x_
                                sf.y_ = y_
                                sf.prd = prd

                # summary
                tf.summary.scalar('loss1/loss', sf.loss_mse)
                tf.summary.scalar('loss1/loss_perc', sf.loss_perc)
                tf.summary.scalar('loss1/abs_error', sf.abs_error)
                tf.summary.scalar('DG_loss/G', sf.loss_G)
                tf.summary.scalar('DG_loss/D', sf.loss_D)
                tf.summary.scalar('Dloss/ls_d_prd', sf.ls_d_prd)
                tf.summary.scalar('Dloss/ls_d_y', sf.ls_d_y)
                tf.summary.scalar('Dloss/loss_d_prd', sf.loss_d_prd)
                tf.summary.scalar('Dloss/loss_d_y', sf.loss_d_y)
                tf.summary.image('img/x', sf.x_[0:1], max_outputs=1)
                tf.summary.image('img/y', sf.y_[0:1], max_outputs=1)
                tf.summary.image('img/prd', sf.prd[0:1], max_outputs=1)
                sf.mergeall = tf.summary.merge_all()

                avg_grads_G = sf.average_gradients(tower_grads_G)
                avg_grads_D = sf.average_gradients(tower_grads_D)
                sf.train_op_G = sf.opt.apply_gradients(avg_grads_G, global_step=sf.global_step)
                sf.train_op_D = sf.opt.apply_gradients(avg_grads_D)

    # generator
    def gen(sf, x):
        with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            c1 = sf.conv(x, 64, 'c1')
            c2 = sf.conv(c1, 64, 'c2')
            p1 = L.max_pooling2d(c2, 2, 2, name='p1')
            c3 = sf.conv(p1, 128, 'c3')
            c4 = sf.conv(c3, 128, 'c4')
            p2 = L.max_pooling2d(c4, 2, 2, name='p2')
            c5 = sf.conv(p2, 256, 'c5')
            c6 = sf.conv(c5, 256, 'c6')
            p3 = L.max_pooling2d(c6, 2, 2, name='p3')
            c7 = sf.conv(p3, 512, 'c7')
            c8 = sf.conv(c7, 512, 'c8')
            d1 = L.dropout(c8, 0.5, training=sf.istraining, name='d1')
            p4 = L.max_pooling2d(d1, 2, 2, name='p4')
            c9 = sf.conv(p4, 1024, 'c9')
            c10 = sf.conv(c9, 1024, 'c10')
            d2 = L.dropout(c10, 0.5, training=sf.istraining, name='d2')

            u1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D()(d2)
            # u1 = L.conv2d_transpose(d2, 1024, 3, 2, padding='same')
            uc1 = sf.conv(u1, 512, 'uc1', ker_size=2)
            mg1 = tf.concat([d1, uc1], axis=3, name='mg1')
            c11 = sf.conv(mg1, 512, 'c11')
            c12 = sf.conv(c11, 512, 'c12')

            u2 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D()(c12)
            # u2 = L.conv2d_transpose(c12, 512, 3, 2, padding='same')
            uc2 = sf.conv(u2, 256, 'uc2', ker_size=2)
            mg2 = tf.concat([c6, uc2], axis=3, name='mg2')
            c13 = sf.conv(mg2, 256, 'c13')
            c14 = sf.conv(c13, 256, 'c14')

            u3 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D()(c14)
            # u3 = L.conv2d_transpose(c14, 256, 3, 2, padding='same')
            uc3 = sf.conv(u3, 128, 'uc3', ker_size=2)
            mg3 = tf.concat([c4, uc3], axis=3, name='mg3')
            c15 = sf.conv(mg3, 128, 'c15')
            c16 = sf.conv(c15, 128, 'c16')

            u4 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D()(c16)
            # u4 = L.conv2d_transpose(c16, 128, 3, 2, padding='same')
            uc4 = sf.conv(u4, 64, 'uc4', ker_size=2)
            mg4 = tf.concat([c2, uc4], axis=3, name='mg4')
            c17 = sf.conv(mg4, 64, 'c17')
            c18 = sf.conv(c17, 64, 'c18')

            c19 = sf.conv(c18, 2, 'c19')

            # tf.summary.histogram('c19', c19)
            prd = sf.conv(c19, 1, 'prd', ker_size=1, act=tf.nn.sigmoid)
            return prd


    # discriminator
    def disc(sf, prd):
        with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            c1 = sf.conv(prd, 16, 'c1')
            p1 = L.max_pooling2d(c1, 2, 2, name='p1')
            c2 = sf.conv(p1, 16, 'c2')
            p2 = L.max_pooling2d(c2, 2, 2, name='p2')
            c3 = sf.conv(p2, 32, 'c3')
            p3 = L.max_pooling2d(c3, 2, 2, name='p3')
            c4 = sf.conv(p3, 32, 'c4')
            p4 = L.max_pooling2d(c4, 2, 2, name='p4')
            c5 = sf.conv(p4, 64, 'c5')
            p5 = L.max_pooling2d(c5, 2, 2, name='p5')
            c6 = sf.conv(p5, 64, 'c6')
            p6 = L.max_pooling2d(c6, 2, 2, name='p6')
            c7 = sf.conv(p6, 128, 'c7')
            p7 = L.max_pooling2d(c7, 2, 2, name='p7')
            c8 = sf.conv(p7, 128, 'c8', pad='valid')
            line1 = tf.reshape(c8, [c8.shape[0], -1])
            fc1 = L.dense(line1, 128, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
            d1 = L.dropout(fc1, 0.5, training=sf.istraining)
            fc2 = L.dense(d1, 1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
            return fc2

    def conv(sf, x, filters, name, ker_size=3,
             act=tf.nn.leaky_relu,
             pad='same',
             init=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()):
        return L.conv2d(x, filters, ker_size,
                        activation=act,
                        padding=pad,
                        kernel_initializer=init,
                        name=name)

    def get_xy(sf, train_flag):
        def fn1():
            xy_dict = sf.train_iterator.get_next()
            return xy_dict[0], xy_dict[1]

        def fn2():
            xy_dict = sf.test_iterator.get_next()
            return xy_dict[0], xy_dict[1]

        return tf.cond(train_flag, fn1, fn2)

    def average_gradients(sf, tower_grads):
        average_grads = []
        for grad_and_vars in zip(*tower_grads):
            grads = []
            for g, _ in grad_and_vars:
                expend_g = tf.expand_dims(g, 0)
                grads.append(expend_g)
            grad = tf.concat(grads, 0)
            grad = tf.reduce_mean(grad, 0)
            v = grad_and_vars[0][1]
            grad_and_var = (grad, v)
            average_grads.append(grad_and_var)
        return average_grads
```